# How to solve a congruence using Fermat's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* and I'm trying to understand an example (later I have to solve several problems of the same type).

> **Little Theorem of Fermat**: If $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime not dividing $a$, then p divides $a^{p-1}-1$, that is $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. 
>   As a corollary, if $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, then  $a^p \equiv  a\pmod{p}$."

So far so good. But then Fraleigh gives the following example.

> *Example 1*: Compute the reminder of $8^{103}$ when divided by $13$.
>
> Using Fermat's Theorem, we have 
>   $$8^{103}\equiv (8^{12})^8(8^7) \equiv (1^8)(8^7)\equiv 8^7 \equiv (-5)^7\equiv (25)^3(-5)\equiv (-1)^3(-5)\equiv 5\pmod{13}$$

I'm lost after the $4_{th}$ $\equiv$. Where did that $(-5)^7$ came from?

For those who have it, its chapter $20$ of the $7_{th}$ edition.

Comment: You get it as $8=13-5\equiv -5 \bmod 13$

Comment: Hint:  $8+5=13$.

Comment: Switching to the negative residue is often a useful trick in quickly calculating results like this.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\equiv b\bmod n$ and $c\equiv d\bmod n$, then $ac\equiv bd\bmod n$.

We have $8\equiv -5\bmod 13$, therefore $8^7\equiv (-5)^7\bmod 13$.

Answer (score 1):

$8 \equiv -5 \pmod{13}$ because $13 \mid 8 - (-5) = 13$ and so we also know that if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ then $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{m}$ and so you have that $8 \equiv -5 \pmod{13} \implies 8^7 \equiv (-5)^7 \pmod{13}$

Answer (score 0):

$8\equiv -5$ (mod 13)

since $13|((-5)-(8))$.